# Series expansion: Taylor series takes huge amount of time

Tags: series-expansion

I'm working on a notebook, trying to expand the root of a cubic polynomial in Taylor series.  When I type:

```
Series[(Sqrt[46656 a^2 - 864 (3 2^(1/3) a^(2/3) + 2 a B)^3] + 216 a)^(1/3) , {a, 0, 2}]
```

*Mathematica* takes an indefinite amount of time and I am forced to halt execution.  After this occurs, even simple functions like `Exp[x]` will not compute and I have to restart the kernel.

Am I doing something wrong here?
My computer is a month old, so I know the problem isn't old hardware.

Comment: Works for me, but takes a bit more than two minutes on an i7-2820QM.

Comment: Do you really need an exact, symbolic result?  It is likely to be huge so it may not be useful to you.  You could convert the input to inexact numbers to a certain precision and work with that.

Comment: `Series[N[(Sqrt[46656 a^2 - 864 (3 2^(1/3) a^(2/3) + 2 a bb)^3] + 
     216 a)^(1/3), 30], {a, 0, 2}]`

Comment: You're not doing anything incorrect here. It seems that the Series code is using a fairly high order in some internal computations. I need to check whether there is solid reason for that, or whether it needs to be tamed to some extent.

Comment: If you take @Szabolcs advice: `Series[(Sqrt[46656 a^2 - 864 (3 2^(1/3) a^(2/3) + 2 a B)^3] + 
     216 a)^(1/3) // N, {a, 0, 2}]` works very quickly

Comment: @YvesKlett It is indeed quick, but the result appears to be incorrect, probably due to precision loss.  `N[..., somePrecision]` seems to give consistent results, but using machine precision (i.e. `N[...]`) doesn't.  There seems to be a cancellation in the coefficient of the `a^2` term under the square root in the original expression.  Maybe that's what's causing the numerical problems.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If I use `ExpandAll` to get rid of the `a^2` term under the square root, then even the numericized version is very very slow: `Series[N@ExpandAll[(Sqrt[
       46656 a^2 - 864 (3 2^(1/3) a^(2/3) + 2 a B)^3] + 216 a)^(1/
      3)], {a, 0, 2}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs eeek! Thanks for the sanity check! One up for symbolic calculation, I guess.

Comment: @Szabolcs It will be faster in the next version, assuming I didn't break anything.

Comment: Actually I was wrong saying that the symbolic output might be too large.  `FullSimplify[Series[...], B<0]` gives a very neat output, if you're prepared to wait for `Series` to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're interested in the series expansion for positive values of the parameter `a`, you can use:

```
FullSimplify @ Series[
    (Sqrt[46656 a^2 - 864 (3 2^(1/3) a^(2/3) + 2 a B)^3] + 216 a)^(1/3),
    {a, 0, 2},
    Assumptions -> a>0
] //TeXForm
```

> $6 \sqrt[3]{a}+2 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt{a} \sqrt{-B}+\frac{2}{3} 2^{2/3} a^{2/3} B+\frac{2}{27}
>    a^{5/6} (-B)^{3/2}-\frac{4}{81} a \left(\sqrt[3]{2} B^2\right)+\frac{5 a^{7/6}
>    (-B)^{5/2}}{243 \sqrt[3]{2}}+\frac{8 a^{4/3} B^3}{2187}+\frac{35 a^{3/2}
>    (-B)^{7/2}}{6561\ 2^{2/3}}+\frac{8\ 2^{2/3} a^{5/3} B^4}{19683}+\frac{2555 a^{11/6}
>    (-B)^{9/2}}{4251528}-\frac{496 a^2 \left(\sqrt[3]{2}
>    B^5\right)}{1594323}+O\left(a^{13/6}\right)$